# How to replace every element x of a 2-D tensor with f(x)?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to replace every element x in a 2-D tensor with a function of that element f(x).

For a 1-D tensor, tf.map_fn() can do the job. I seek a similar solution for higher-order tensors.

Comment: Can't you just do a 2D map? Map inside the map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply flatten and reshape:

```
tf.reshape(tf.map_fn(f, tf.reshape(a, [-1])), a.shape)
```

Comment: Is this method faster than the use of numpy.vectorize?

Comment: They cannot be compared. Numpy operations lie outside of a tensorflow graph.